# Record the sound and play it back with changed pitch

Tags: iphone, ios

I have to implement a iphone application which will record user's voice as you starts speaking, and change the pitch of the recorded sound and play it back. I am able to record the audio on the detection of the sound by the help of AVAudiorecorder, and using Dirac library I have changed the pitch of recorded sound. The problem with this approach is that the output sound is noisy enough. I got the response for using SoundEngine but I didn't get the way to implement it. Can anyone please explain me about any other way to implement this?

```
my code//
        -(void)initialSetup
    { 
        count=0; 
        silenceTime=0;

    //[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
    recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleLossless] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f.%@",[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]*1000.0,                  @"caf"]]];
    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];
    //recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] init];
    [recorder setDelegate:self];
    [recorder updateMeters];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    //[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
    //In Order To Move Sound To The Speaker
    //UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    //AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof(audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);

    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audio.caf"];
    recordedTmpFile1 =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    recordSetting1 =   [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    recordSetting1 =   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                        //[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4],AVFormatIDKey,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                        AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                        AVSampleRateKey,nil];
    recorder1 = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile1 settings:recordSetting1 error:&error];
    [recorder1 prepareToRecord];
    [recorder1 setDelegate:self];
    if(recorder) 
    {
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];
        double val=[recorder peakPowerForChannel:0];
        NSLog(@"The Very First Value Of The Recorder Is=%f",val);
        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"error in initilising of the recorder=%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}


-(void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer                      
{ 
    [recorder updateMeters];
    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    //NOISE FILERATION ALGORITHMS
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10,(0.05 *[recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    double audioMonitorResults1 = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * audioMonitorResults1;
    double audioMonitorResults;
    audioMonitorResults= [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0];
    NSLog(@"This time only  frequency is==>%f",audioMonitorResults1);
    //if (audioMonitorResults1 >0.020)
    if(audioMonitorResults1 > .05)//the value of audioMonitorResults may be equal to -10 for device
    {

        [recorder1 updateMeters];
        recorder1.meteringEnabled=YES;
        //recorder.meteringEnabled=YES;
        [recorder1 record];
        NSLog(@"SOUND IS DETECTED");
        NSLog(@"%f",[recorder1 peakPowerForChannel:0]);
        NSLog(@"Recording is going on");
        count=1;
        silenceTime=0;

    }
    else
    {

        NSLog(@"NO SOUND IS DETECTED");
        silenceTime=silenceTime+0.3;
        if(count==1 && silenceTime>1)
        { 

            [levelTimer invalidate];
            [recorder1 stop];

        }

    }

}
- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"Recorder stop delegate is processing");
    if(flag)
    {
        NSLog(@"Player has finished successfully");
        [self playRecording];
    }
    else
    { 
        NSLog(@"problem in recording.......not recorded");
    }
}
```

Comment: y not u use Dirac player to play that changed pitch sound??/

Comment: i have already used the Dirac Player in this.

Comment: can u tell me Is Dirac player not efficient to play that changed pitch sound??

Comment: No,Dirac Player is good enough to change the pitch of sound .my problem is that the output sound which is played after the recording is noisy enough.is there any other way to record th enoise free audio on detection of sound.thanks for your responce....

Comment: [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err]; r u using this??

Comment: i m using AVAudioRecorder to record the sound

Comment: [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err]; use this line too while recording audio

Comment: i tried, but it  doesn't effect the sound....still noisy....

Comment: @NikhilBansal plz help me if u have knowledge about this......

Comment: u still stuck with it???

Comment: coz the problem is still unsolved......how can i resolved the problem of noise.......hoping help from your side..

Comment: i still not understanding which kind of noise is there??

Comment: actually i m using avaudiorecorder to record the sound on detection of the noise and once when the sound is recorded i m using diracplayer to change the pitch of the recorded sound .after doing the oputput sound i get is noisy.

Comment: kis type ki noise aa ri hai bhai??

Comment: khrrrrr......khrrrrr aa rahi hai awaz ke sath.....

Comment: i have edited my question plz see it once.......@nikhil

Comment: in playRecording i m just playing the recorded sound file which is stored in document directory by dirac player         mDiracAudioPlayer = [[DiracAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile1 channels:1 error:&error];
        [mDiracAudioPlayer setDelegate:self];
        [mDiracAudioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
        [mDiracAudioPlayer changePitch:1.8];
        
       
        [mDiracAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
       
        [mDiracAudioPlayer play];

Comment: when u recording sound,then is that recorded sound also consist of that noisy sound?

Comment: yes! it is the main problem, i want to solve

Comment: bas thats the reason recorded sound should not have noise khrrr khrrr

Comment: mera matlab ki agar mai noise free sound record karta hu to uski pitch change krne ke bad  sound noise-free  hogi.kya yeh sahi approach hai?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11874/discussion-between-alok-sinha-and-nikhil-bansal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How to detect the sound?
   I solved my first problem with the help of a tutorial..here is the link for this,
   link: http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/
   Here we can easily understand the recording of the sound on detection of some noise.
2. How to change the pitch of the recorded sound and play back.
   Second problem I faced in changing the pitch of the sound. As we can only record the sound with the help of `AVAudioRecorder` we can’t alter the pitch by that.
   For this purpose I used an external library *DIRAC*. 
   [Here is the link for the Dirac library.](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/)
   This comes up with some sample project (for mobile apps as well as desktop apps)about the implementation of the dirac library to the application.

Another way I found to solve this issue by implementing Cocoas2D, Cocos Denshion with Dirac. Because the above proess was not working well with my application.
[Here is the link for implementing this](http://www.mediafire.com/?dofz0hofjrlkrg9) (a sample project about the changing the pitch and play the recorded sound).

I found [another link](http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/page/25) related to sound recording.

Comment: How did you mangage to detect the sound and record without a delay at the start of the record ?

Comment: link: http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/   it will detect the frequency and then start recording.and plz upvote the question so that other can also see it

Comment: I got I slight lag cutting off the first part of the first letter. I solved it by running two recorders and alternating, so that when the monitor detected the required sound it was already recording.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is an easier solution. Use the rate feature of the audio player. It ranges between 0.1f - 2.0f where higher number means faster and squeekier pitch and lower number means slow dragged out sound (deep voice)

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&err];
        player.volume = 0.4f;
        player.enableRate=YES;
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player setNumberOfLoops:0];
        player.rate=2.0f;
        [player play];
```

Comment: This code is used to increase speech rate not for pitch(like karoke)