# AVAudioRecorder change recorded pitch

Tags: iphone, ios

I am making an app that records users sound and plays it back to them in high pitch. (like a chipmunk). This is for iOS 5.0 or above with Xcode 4.6

This question has been asked here before

[Record the sound and play it back with changed pitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549317/record-the-sound-and-play-it-back-with-changed-pitch)

What I wanted to know is that is there any apple out of the box apis / functions / settings that I can use with AVAudioRecorder or AVAudioPlayer to change the pitch of recorded sound? I hate to add an external DIRAC library if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `AVAudioRecorder`, but `AVAudioPlayer` has a `rate` property which allows you to play things back at up to 2x.  Can't say if that will sound sufficiently like a chipmunk though.

Comment: I used the AVAudioPlayer rate option but it has no effect. See code above

Comment: Missed that, but the docs say that the rate only goes up to 2.0.

Comment: i tried all number between 0.1 - 2.0 and nothing works. Not sure what is it? There is another post with the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131631/avaudioplayer-rate I tried all the answers there too

Comment: Needed to add audioPlayer.rate=2.0f; (float)